# Visio XML Parsing

Tags: java, xml-parsing, visio

Am trying to parse a visio XML file.I am not able to get the basic difference between Fillforeground and Fillbackground. Can any one clarify the difference between the both in terms of VISIO?

Answer (score 2):

The "FillBackground" is Partnern color (used if you have a pattern take a look at the screenshot):

[image]